# How can I start learning cloud for sales profile

Tags: google-cloud-storage, paas, amazon-cloudsearch, iaas

I have recently joined a new sales team. This profile is about selling AWS and GCP services. I want to know how should I start learning cloud technology over internet?

Answer (score 0):

For AWS, your company will have a partner account. Sign in and go to the Training section. AWS has some very good courses to get you up to speed quickly.

[AWS Partner Training](https://www.aws.training/)

Google also has a similar program. Then there are the third part companies such as A Cloud Guru, Linux Academy, Cloud Academy, Udemy and a massive collection of cloud related videos on YouTube.